# How can I install Ubuntu in my HP Pavilion G4 notebook?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hp

I have an HP Pavilion G4 notebook. I have Windows on it and am trying to dual boot. I have tried to install Ubuntu on it. I tried to boot from CD, pen drive and even tried to do it by downloading Ubuntu from online. I tried different versions of Ubuntu (12.04 and 13.04). I tried the boot helper in the CD as well.

Every time I try to boot and install Ubuntu, my laptop hangs in the beginning after the Ubuntu logo appears.

Comment: how much time you wait on that purple screen( after the Ubuntu Logo)?

Comment: Consider to launch a bug on bugs.launchpad.net.

Comment: I waited 10-15 minutes maybe. (I went outside for a work and came back to see the same thing on my screen.)

Comment: @SauravKumar  Ok, I'll do that.